# How do I unlock /var/lib/dpkg/lock?

Tags: software-center, dpkg, dropbox, lock

I attempted to install dropbox on my Ubuntu system, but now I am unable to install or uninstall any software. I get this error:

```
E: Unable to lock the administration directory /var/lib/dpkg/lock?
```

I have already tried killing `dpkg` and restarting it `sudo kill -TERM PID` but it immediately tries to finish the installation again and gets stuck.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock` should do the trick. You can use `ps afx|grep dpkg` to check if there is still a process runnning at the same time. `sudo killall dpkg` will stop all running dpkg processes.

If you need to cancel the dropbox installation, try
`sudo dpkg --force-remove-reinstreq --remove nautilus-dropbox`

Comment: I did not use the first command, as I've heard this can cause a serious problems if the program is still running. The sudo dpkg --force-remove-reinstreq --remove nautilus-dropbox did the trick though.

Comment: Good answer but manually removing the lock file should be a last resort.

Comment: No such file or directory: /var/lib/dpkg/lock

Comment: Use `pgrep -f 'dpkg|apt'` instead of `ps ... | grep ...` because it's wrong; `ps ... | grep -v grep | grep ...` is the old way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

It means that software center or another terminal is still running a package operation, force removing it is not really recommended as it can cause corruption, but try closing those and if that doesn't do the trick then reboot and just open a terminal window and nothing else to install/do a package operation

Comment: With auto-update, it is often that `apt-get` automatically starts on a reboot. The OP has a problem with installation failing, so I do not think that this would help much.

Answer (score -3):

The `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` is actually a file. If you think it is important, just **rename** it don't want to remove it.

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-backup
```

Comment: This makes no sense, even if backup everything will not harm you. If you remove a lock manually is assumed to break the process flow that creates the lock, so there's no reason to backup it. Run again the process then the lock will be created "on-demand".

Comment: That file is empty anyway.