# i can't update my ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, lts

Every time when I enter the commands `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade`, it shows:

```
(You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpam-systemd : Depends: systemd (= 229-4ubuntu12) but 229-4ubuntu4 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.)
```

and after that when i entered `sudo apt-get -f install` this shows up:

```
(E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?)
```

What do I do next? I can't update my pc. I also want to install Windows XP alongside.

Comment: Please retry `sudo apt-get -f install` (with `sudo`). Does it say `Permission denied` again?

Comment: Check if you in `sudo` group with `groups $USERNAME`

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/498102/how-do-i-unlock-var-lib-dpkg-lock